# Apache Drill web UI authencation failing

Tags: apache-drill

i am new to apache Drill, I added the below code to `drill-override.conf` :

```
drill.exec {
   security.user.auth {
         enabled: true,
         packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security",
         impl: "pam",
         pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]
    } 
}
```

But it's giving an error while logging through Web UI saying -

> username and password invalid

How can I assign my root user to Drill?

Comment: :- Have got any solution for this problem.?

Comment: @dev ツ:- Can you help me regarding this problem..?

Comment: @Sanjiv I am not working on drill now-a-days.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add PAM lib ( [libjpam.so](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpam/files/jpam/jpam-1.1/) ) to say `<jpamdir>`

edit `<drill_home>/conf/drill-env.sh` add:

```
export DRILL_JAVA_LIB_PATH="-Djava.library.path=<jpamdir>"
export DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=<jpamdir>"
export DRILL_SHELL_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=<jpamdir>"
```

and make changes to `<drill_home>/conf/drill-override.conf`:

```
  drill.exec: {
    cluster-id: "",
    zk.connect: "",
    impersonation: {
      enabled: true,
      max_chained_user_hops: 3
    },
    security: {          
            auth.mechanisms : ["PLAIN"],
             },
    security.user.auth: {
            enabled: true,
            packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security",
            impl: "pam",
            pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]
     }
   }
```

Run drill as root

```
sudo <drill_home>/bin/sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=local -n <user> -p <password>
```

Login drill web-ui/client with Linux user